# Proof of the Conditional Exchange

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove the Conditional Exchange:

$$(P \implies Q) \iff (\neg P \lor Q)$$

Sadly, I can't provide an attempt because, well, I'm not quite sure where to start. I can't see any way to use a direct proof, so possibly an assumption of some form might be the best course of action. My biggest problem is how to get from the Conditional to the disjunction. Is there some property or rule that I'm forgetting or don't know? To my knowledge, the Conditional Exchange is the only way to  "get" from Conditional to disjunction.

And yes, I've constructed a truth table for this before. I'm trying to find a formal proof.

Comment: What rules do you have?  There are many different formal proof systems, so it all depends on exactly what rules you have.  That said, you probably want to set this up as a Proof by Contradiction ... do you have a rule that formalizes that proof technique?

Comment: @Bram28 No limitations (I can use any inference rule, relation, etc), this isn't from a textbook or course -- I just thought it up. And I'm not sure what you mean by a rule that formalizes the proof technique. Just trying to construct a formal proof.

Comment: OK, I added a proof in the system Fitch ... in this system the $\neg \ Intro$ rule is the formalization of Proof by Contradiction, as you can see on lines 6 and 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof of going from the conditional to the disjunction in the system I like to use myself:

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks!